# let dropdown menu disappear if I click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this search box
[search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiIW3.png)

And I've written a function to let the search box disappear when the user clicks outside or presses the Esc button.

The problem is, that when the user clicks on the search field, then search button "Suchen" in the menu does not disappear.

[after search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozYa0.png)

My code:

```
//Outside click
$("body").click(function(){
    jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeOut(500);
});
$("body").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 27 || e.which === 27 ){
        jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeOut(500);
    }
});
$(".pg-suche-lupe-button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How can solve this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of `$(e.target).hasClass` on the body click.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$("body").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("searchfieldbox")) {
    jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeOut(500);
  }
});

$("#input").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeIn(500);
});
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.which === 27) {
    jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

```css
.searchfieldbox {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<div class="searchfieldbox"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work 
this is the whole function 
`$("body").click(function(){
  jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeOut(500);
 });
 $("body").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 27 || e.which === 27 ){
   jQuery('.searchfieldbox').fadeOut(500);
  }
 });
 $(".pg-suche-lupe-button").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(".pg-suche-lupe").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(".searchfieldbox").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });`

Comment: first user click on search icon to search i enabled outside click and stoppet function inside the whole search box  thats why i have this problem but your code does not solve it

Comment: @MolhamAlNasr share a working example using `<>` button in edit mode or [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/)